# Checkbox text, pushing actual checkbox to the left

Tags: java, android

Please take a look at following image:

[image]

As you can see, the text which belongs to Checkbox is pushing corresponding Checkbox to the left. My XML is simple: 1 LinearLayout with gravity: center, and orientation:vertical. And other Views are as you can see are CheckBox and Button. All with same attributes ( width and height: wrap_content, and some margin between them.

So my question is simple: How can I make Checkboxes align vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@soma-web's advice is sound.

Another way you could do this is:

1. Create another vertical LinearLayout inside your LinearLayout, set its width to wrap_content
2. Put all the checkboxes inside that LinearLayout.

The smaller LinearLayout will wrap its width the longest checkbox, but will align them to the left. This way, your internal LinearLayout will be centered, but the checkboxes won't be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, this is also an approach! nice

Answer (score 1):

Give your LinearLayout a padding and make the gravity go left?
Or just use a Tablelayout and use a CheckBox without text and a textview to the right of it with a centered gravity

Answer (score 0):

For your linear layout give:

```
android:gravity = "left|center"
```